# Getting useful information for Test Automation Framework

Tags: testing, taf, mtaf

I'm having much more trouble with MTAF than what it's worth, and I am hoping some others here have had more extensive experience with it. The documentation is simply awful and it scares me that Magento even allowed it to be released in this state. I found a fork of MTAF at https://github.com/vashigor/taf that at least works better with my newer version of Magento, but sadly the documentation isn't any more clear.

In any case, it's my understanding that MTAF had a comprehensive amount of tests through all of the basic functions of Magento. This seems to be true for Admin tasks, but what about frontend?

I don't see any tests that validate the homepage, a category, or a product page. There's a test that adds a product to the cart, but where are the more basic things first? If I have to build them from scratch, I might as well abandon MTAF and go with CasperJS/ZombieJS or equivalent.

If these things are indeed available:
How can I tell MTAF to only run frontend tests? If I want to validate that the user experience is solid, I don't need to spend hours running any Admin tasks to do that.
How can I modify those tests to reflect the current theme?
Do I make a new directory to put these things, or should I edit the original files in place? (And which files?!)

Sorry for the million questions, but trying to research any solid usability steps have been wholly unhelpful, and I'm slowly losing my sanity. Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: Could you please split you questions into separate posts?

Answer (score 1):

A better starting point is the [bugathon_march_2013](https://github.com/magento/bugathon_march_2013) repo. The [wiki](https://github.com/magento/bugathon_march_2013/wiki) has detailed documentation about how to set it up:

- [QA Tools & Framework](https://github.com/magento/bugathon_march_2013/wiki/QA-Tools-&-Framework)
- [QAExample](https://github.com/magento/bugathon_march_2013/wiki/QAExample)

Comment: Thank you for the response.. You're right, that would have been a much better starting point when I first touched TAF, I wish I would have seen that instead! However, this doesn't help answer any of the questions I've posed above :(

Comment: You have way too many questions regarding MTAF, all in one. If you have a look at what is described in the bugathon project and you can run the testsuite, you can find all the answers you need.

Comment: Well, I'm going to respectfully disagree with that, as I would have no need to ask if it were that clear and straightforward. If you would like to edit your initial response to back this statement up with direct quotes from these documents as they correlate to my exact questions, I'll be more than happy to mark it as the answer.